# How to resolve "reportMissingImports" warning in a Colab notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to load a notebook into another notebook in the Google Colab environment, and while the function is working (simple adding of numbers), there is still a warning: Import "demo_function" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports). I don't like code with warnings, but I am failing to resolve this warning.

How can I make this import work without the warning on the last line?

```
# file with the function to load:
# /content/gdrive/MyDrive/.../Notebooks/demo_function.ipynb

# Insert the directory
import sys
path_to_module = r'/content/gdrive/MyDrive/.../Notebooks'
sys.path.append(path_to_module)

# copying the file to the local runtime:
!cp /content/gdrive/MyDrive/.../Notebooks/demo_function.py /content/demo_function.py

# There is a warning, but the function will load:
from demo_function import add_numbers # the demo_function has a warning
add_numbers(1,10)

# Function in the other notebook:
# def add_numbers(a, b):
#    return a + b
```